# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: : org/springframework/aop/config/AbstractInterceptorDrivenBeanDefinitionDecorator with Spring Security

Tags: spring, maven, spring-security

I just don't get why do I have this error if I've already got aop library.

My spring-security-context.xml, the place I've got crash looks like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<security:http>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:http-basic />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="user" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

I can't add my pom.xml because of code limits on question, But it has:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId> 
    <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I can't add my pom.xml because of code limits on question, But it has: `      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
          <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
          <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
`

Comment: <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
          <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>

Comment: Post the full depenencies, judging from this you are mixing different versions of jars from Spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#maven-bom).

It seems to be that Spring Security brings wrong (old) dependencies with itself.

The solution I've found completely resolved the problem.